# Не работает код не могу понять в чем заключается ошибка

Tags: python, рекурсия, числа-фибоначчи

Добрый день написал код в котором хочу использовать рекурсию Фибоначчи и самописный декоратор к данной рекурсии но он выдает ошибку:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:/Users/Arenter/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py", line 10, in 
> def fibonacci(n):
> File "C:/Users/Arenter/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py", line 8, in memo
> return wrapper()
> File "C:/Users/Arenter/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py", line 6, in wrapper
> *cache*[args] = func(*args)
> TypeError: fibonacci() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'"

вот код:

```
def memo(func):
    _cache_ = dict()
    def wrapper(*args):
        if args in _cache_:
            return _cache_[args]
        _cache_[args] = func(*args)
        return _cache_[args]
    return wrapper()
@memo
def fibonacci(n):
    if n in (1, 2):
        return 1
    if n in (3,):
        print(3,)

    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)


print(fibonacci(10))
```

подскажите, пожалуйста, где я ошибся?

Comment: `return wrapper()` -> `return wrapper`

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка в строке `return wrapper()`.
Скобки не нужны, правильно будет: `return wrapper`.